# How can I tell the difference between an initialized struct and an uninitialized struct?

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I am sending student records over a socket. The database sends the client the number of students in the list and then sends the records one at a time. The problem I am coming across is that when there are no students the list starts with an uninitialized record. I thought about adding a new field to the records that stated if they were a new record or had been filled but that would mean changing A LOT of the code.

Is there an easy way to check a record to see if it has been filled. Below is the structure for the student records.

```
typedef struct student{
    char lname[10], initial, fname[10];
    unsigned long SID;
    float GPA;
} SREC;

typedef struct node{
    SREC student;
    int deleted;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} NODE;
```

This is what initialization is done for the starting empty node.

```
NODE *lname = calloc( 1, sizeof(NODE) );
lname->left = NULL;
lname->right = NULL;
lname->deleted = 0;
```

Comment: Yap, keep track of it manually.

Comment: Well, how do you know that the left or right node is uninitialized?  Why should that be different for the root?

Comment: Hmm... I only now just noticed this is using calloc... as such the memory should be initialized to all 0's... can you restate your question?  What is not initialized?

Comment: You say "The database sends the client the number of students in the list and then sends the records one at a time." If there are no records won't the database send you a count of 0, in which case you can act appropriately without having to mess around trying to determine if you've got a valid record or not?

Answer (score 3):

1. If the null pointer on your system has an all-zero bit pattern (and it probably does), you don't need any of that code after `calloc`.
2. You can track if a record has been initialized by looking at any field that doesn't have a legitimate all-zero value.  Maybe the `lname` or `SID` fields?

Comment: Thanks Carl. I wasn't sure is NULL was all zeros or not. And I added the deleted field later and just assigned it values where I thought it needed it, even though calloc would have done it for me. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

An uninitialized record could have anything in it.  In fact, at a very low probability it could coincidentally have something interesting, or even the written exposition at the beginning of Star Wars in it.  You can't rely on the contents of uninitialized memory.

As such you'll need to introduce something to track whether or not the data in the structure is filled in, and deliberately set it to the appropriate value (which is, in a way, initializing the structure.)

Comment: In this case, it can only have zeros in it.

Comment: @H2CO3: I think it does. In short, the answer is "you can't".

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll have to go through all of the code and update it for a new field.